# Android: Get Number of Files within Zip?

Tags: java, android, zip, android-assets

I have a question that seems easy but I cannot seem to get it to work properly.

I have a zip file within my 'assets' folder that I need to unzip and I have a `ProgessBar` in which I want to display to the user how the progress is going.

I have everything working but I want to set the `ProgessBar` max value to be the number of files within the zip file. The number of files within this folder will sometimes change so I want the `ProgessBar` to be relative to how many files are contained within the zip.

I'm using the `ZipInputStream`-API but does not seem there is a way to get the number of files within the zip file. The only way I can of think of is doing this:

```
   ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(getAssets().open(
                                "myFile.zip"));
   int numFiles = 0;
   int increment = 0;
   while (zin.getNextEntry() != null) {
     numFiles++;
    }

    ZipEntry ze = null;
    //Set the Max..value here..
    progessBar.setMax(numFiles);                
    while ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) {
       increment++;
       progessBar.setProgress(increment);
    }
```

This works but having two while loops seems a bit redundant which are basically doing the same thing.

I know that there is a `ZipFile`-API which has a `size()`-method, but it requires a path to the file and since my file is located within the 'assets' folder I am pretty sure the only way to read from this directory is by streaming.

Is there a way for me to accomplish this?

Answer (score 9):

Thanks for the answers. What I ended up doing using the: `AssetFileDescriptor` API to get the file size of the zip file and setting that as the `ProgessBar.setMax()` value. Then as I loop through the zip contents I increment the progress by using each entries file size. This works but the only concern I have is that the `AssetFileDescriptor.getLength()` value as well as the `ZipEntry.getSize()` values return a `long` value so I am forced to cast them to an integer before I can set the max and/or increment the `ProgessBar` so there is a slight possibility I might overload an integer value causing an exception but this is not likely because I do not anticipate my file sizes ever getting bigger than the max holding capacity of an integer.

```
ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(getAssets().open(
                            "myFile.zip"));
ZipEntry ze = null;
AssetFileDescriptor mydisc = getAssets().openFd("myFile.zip");
//Size of the zip package
long size = mydisc.getLength();
long increment = 0;
dialog.setMax((int) size);
while ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) {
     increment += (int) ze.getSize();
     progessBar.setProgess((int)increment);
     //do more stuff..
}
```

Not the best solution but it works.

I'm aware of the `ZipFile` API but it requires a string to be passed in but I am not sure what the path is to that directory or how to get it?

Comment: getting " java.io.FileNotFoundException: This file can not be opened as a file descriptor; it is probably compressed" with this method

Answer (score 6):

Use `ZipFile` API, There is a `size` method that returns the number of `ZipEntries` in the `ZipFile`. You can read from assets folder.

example:

```
int zipEntriesCount(String path) throws IOException {

     ZipFile zf= new ZipFile(path);
     return zf.size();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your basic problem seems to be that you have to do `progressBar.setMax()` before you start reading the file, and you are setting the max based on the number of files.

Have you thought about doing `progressBar.setMax(zin.getSize())` and then keeping track of how many bytes you've written when you call `progressBar.setProgress()`, instead of how many files you've read? This should solve your problem and will give you (imho) a more accurate progress bar.

Comment: but what if one file is 10kb and another one is 10mb and there are only two files in the archive?

Comment: Won't work, because ZipInputStream doesn't have any method called getSize.

Comment: not sure about the `getSize()`  but great idea about setting progress based on file size, not the zip files counts. i was reading the whole zip two times and it will cost me a lot of time because i have map tiles and my zip has 130,000 files in it so, for reporting progress based on writing bytes is really efficient and faster. basicely double timing! thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1):

this is my solution based on @davorb idea which is to show progress based on file size and not content of zip file.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;

public class ZipUtility {
    private final String TAG = "Decompress";
    private ZipExtractionCallback zipExtractionCallback;

    public ZipUtility(ZipExtractionCallback zipExtractionCallback) {
        this.zipExtractionCallback = zipExtractionCallback;
    }
//
//    private void unzipFromAssets(Context context, String zipFile, String destination) {
//        try {
//            if (destination == null || destination.length() == 0)
//                destination = context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
//            new File(destination).delete();
//            InputStream stream = context.getAssets().open(zipFile);
//            unzip(stream, destination);
////            SharedPreferenceHelper.Write(context,
////                    SharedPreferenceConst.SharedPreferenceName,
////                    SharedPreferenceConst.MapExtracted,
////                    "1");
//        } catch (IOException e) {
//            e.printStackTrace();
//        }
//    }

    private boolean deleteDirectory(String file) /*throws IOException, InterruptedException */ {

        try {
            if (new File(file).exists()) {
                String deleteCommand = "rm -rf " + file/*.getAbsolutePath()*/;
                Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
                Process process = runtime.exec(deleteCommand);
                process.waitFor();
                return true;
            }
        } catch (Exception ignore) {
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void unzipFromPath(Context context, String zipFilePath, String destination) {

        try {
            if (destination == null || destination.length() == 0)
                destination = context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
            zipExtractionCallback.progress(0, "حذف فایل های قدیمی...");
            deleteDirectory(destination + "html");
            unzip(zipFilePath, destination);
            zipExtractionCallback.progress(0, "حذف فایل اضافی...");
            deleteDirectory(zipFilePath);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            zipExtractionCallback.error("خطا هنگام عملیات استخراج : " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        zipExtractionCallback.finish();
    }
//
//    public static void unzip(String zipFile, String location) {
//        try {
//            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(zipFile);
//            unzip(fin, location);
//        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
//            e.printStackTrace();
//        }
//
//    }

    private void unzip(String zipFilePath, String destination) throws IOException {
        long size = new File(zipFilePath).length();
        long decompressedSize = 0;
        InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(new File(zipFilePath));
        dirChecker(destination, "");
//        int entries = 0;
        int total = 0;
        ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(stream);

//        while ((zin.getNextEntry()) != null) {
//            if (entries % 100 == 0)
//                zipExtractionCallback.progress(0, "در حال خواندن محتویات:" + entries + " فایل");
//            entries++;
//        }
        zin.close();
        stream = new FileInputStream(new File(zipFilePath));
        int p = 0;
        long totalBytes = 0;
        int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 10;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        try {
            zin = new ZipInputStream(stream);
            ZipEntry ze = null;
            while ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                decompressedSize += ze.getSize();
                //Log.v(TAG, "Unzipping " + ze.getName());
                if (ze.isDirectory()) {
                    dirChecker(destination, ze.getName());
                } else {
                    File f = new File(destination, ze.getName());
                    if (!f.exists()) {
                        boolean success = f.createNewFile();
                        if (!success) {
                            //Log.w(TAG, "Failed to create file " + f.getName());
                            continue;
                        }
                        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(f);
                        //BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(fout);
                        int count;
                        while ((count = zin.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                            fout.write(buffer, 0, count);
                            //out.write(buffer, 0, count);
                            totalBytes += count;
                        }
                        zin.closeEntry();
                        fout.close();
                    }
                }
//                int progress = 1 + (total++ * 100 / entries);
                if (size < decompressedSize)
                    size = decompressedSize;
                int progress = (int) ( (totalBytes * 100L / size));
                if (p < progress)
                    zipExtractionCallback.progress(progress, "در حال استخراج از حالت فشرده:");
                p = progress;
            }
            zin.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            zipExtractionCallback.error("خطا هنگام عملیات استخراج : " + e.getMessage());
            Log.e(TAG, "unzip", e);
        }
    }

    private void dirChecker(String destination, String dir) {
        File f = new File(destination, dir);

        if (!f.isDirectory()) {
            boolean success = f.mkdirs();
            if (!success) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Failed to create folder " + f.getName());
            }
        }
    }


    public interface ZipExtractionCallback {

        void progress(int progress, String status);

        void finish();

        void error(String error);
    }

}
```

Example of using it :

```
private void ExtractMap(String zipFilePath,Context context) {

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            ZipUtility zipUtility = new ZipUtility(new ZipUtility.ZipExtractionCallback() {
                @Override
                public void progress(int progress, String status) {
                    ((UpdateActivity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                             //todo handle ui
                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void finish() {

                    ((UpdateActivity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            //todo handle ui
                        }
                    });

                }

                @Override
                public void error(String error) {
                    ((UpdateActivity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                           //todo handle ui
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            zipUtility.unzipFromPath(context,
                    zipFilePath,
                    context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator);


        }
    }).start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for lingala.zip4j [Zip4j](https://github.com/srikanth-lingala/zip4j)

```
val fileDescriptorPath = fileDescriptor(zipUri)
val zipFile = ZipFile(fileDescriptorPath, password)
zipFile.use {
    zipSize =  it.fileHeaders.size
}
fileDescriptorPath?.delete()

private fun fileDescriptor(uri: Uri?): File? {
    if (uri == null) return null
    var input: FileInputStream? = null
    var output: FileOutputStream? = null
    val filePath: String = File(context.cacheDir, "tmp.zip").absolutePath
   return try {
       val parcelFileDescriptor: ParcelFileDescriptor = context.contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(uri, "r")!!
       val fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.fileDescriptor
        input = FileInputStream(fileDescriptor)
        output = FileOutputStream(filePath)
        var read: Int
        val bytes = ByteArray(1024)
        while (input.read(bytes).also { read = it } != -1) {
            output.write(bytes, 0, read)
        }
        parcelFileDescriptor.close()
        File(filePath)
    } catch (ignored: IOException) {
        Log.v("pathFileDescriptor", "IOException: ${ignored.message}")
       null
    } finally {
        input?.close()
        output?.close()
    }
}
```